# Run Chai and Mocha tests periodically

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, mocha.js, chai

I have multiple tests, written with Mocha and Chai, that test the behavior and functionality of my web application. I want to be able to run them automatically and periodically, say every hour. Are there any services or software tools that run your tests in a periodic basis?

Answer (score 0):

You can run tests with ([Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/)) or simply with crontab (on linux systems)

**With Jenkins:**

Jenkins can be installed on a Linux server. It can run "builds" periodically or when a commit is pushed on your Github/your custom GIT server. These builds can have one or many steps, for example:

1. Pull from GIT
2. Run NodeJS Server
3. Execute tests

Then you receive a report by email if the test fail. This tool is very customizable thanks to many plugins.

[Full example of test automation with ExpressJS and GitHub](https://www.terlici.com/2015/09/29/automated-testing-with-node-express-github-and-jenkins.html)

**With crontab:**

Another possibility (simplest) is to schedule a task with crontab by typing :

```
crontab -e
```

Example of a Cron :

```
0 * * * * node /path/to/your/script.js
```

This command will be executed every hour with the current user.

More on wikipedia: [Cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)

Comment: Simple reference to a website and not posting the essentials is not allowed. Edit your answer with a non wiki Cron example. For the Jenkins part, I'm not an expert on that topic, you've send just into the bush, got lost and died from dehydration. If you want to refer to Jenkins then add some details on how to do it so I can learn from it. Now it takes me too much time (>5min) to get basic hang of it. Please finish the tour an you'll get the understanding of my comments as well. End of view first answer-post. Fix answer and Enjoy SO ;-)

Comment: So in Jenkins I can upload my current test suite and configure it so that it runs it periodically? And are the tests run on a Jenkin's server or where?

Comment: The thing that confuses me is the following. My tests and my web application are completely decoupled. My entire web application is in a bitbucket repository A and all my tests are in a bitbucket repository B, but it looks like you are referring to a single repository that contains the an entire Java application and its tests. I want to schedule a periodic build in the repository where ONLY my tests scripts reside, does this make sense?

Comment: My tests then take care of interacting with the application, without it having to be in the same repo. So ideally, I would like for Jenkins to take all my files from the test repo and simple run a command like "npm run test" on a command line terminal.

Comment: I understand. Here is an example that can help you: Jenkins run the build when you push on repository A. This build consists of pulling the repository B (tests) and then run the tests. Obviously, your application must be reachable from the Jenkins server :)

Comment: In your Crontab example, isn't that for running only a single script? I'm trying to run a node.js app. I currently run my node.js app in the command line by writing "npm run api-pro", where api-pro is a script in the package.json that invokes test scripts. How can I use Cron for an app and not a script?

Comment: Note that if I try to use the command "npm run api-pro" in Crontab I get an error saying "npm: command not found" (but I don't get that error when running it in my command line).

Comment: You can write several commands in a bash script and execute this script with crontab. For the error, try to use the absolute path of npm (you can get it by typing "which npm")